# Binding complex object to a component

Tags: aurelia

**Introduction**

My goal is to create custom element in aurelia so that I can reuse it across the application.

In this context I've created component called **operator-detail** (*operator-detail.html* and *operator-detail.js*) which will holds information about operator and my plan is to reuse it in several places in application.

In this use case I have *electornicRegistrationForm* object which holds reference to *operatorDetails* and *legalRepresentative*. Both instances are injected into *electornicRegistrationForm* module and will be used as part of wizard allowing user to create a document which will be printed later on.

This *electronicRegistraionForm* is injected into *operatorStep* component.

*operator-detail.html* component I've included in *operatorStep.html* and confirm that component has been rendered correctly.

**Problem**

How to pass (bind) property *operator* from **operatorStep.js** to **operator-detail.html** component so that values from object *operator* are displayed (binded) in a two way binding manner.

In following example, value from *this.operator.firstName* 'First name from operator step' don't get displayed in *operator-detail.html* component.

**Source code**

**electronicRegistrationForm.js**:

```
import { OperatorDetail } from 'common/operator-detail';
import { LegalRepresentative } from 'common/legalRepresentative';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
@inject(OperatorDetail, LegalRepresentative)
export class ElectronicRegistrationForm {
  constructor(operatorDetail, legalRepresentative) {
    this.operator = operatorDetail;
    this.legalRepresentative = legalRepresentative;
  }
}
```

**operator-detail.js**

```
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ValidationRules, ValidationController} from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class OperatorDetail {
  constructor(validationController) {
    this.validationController = validationController;
    this.firstName = '';
  }

  attached() {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure('firstName').displayName('Ime').required()
      .on(this);
  }          
}
```

**operator-detail.html**

```
<template bindable="operatorvalue">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstName" t='first_name'></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" value.bind="operatorvalue.firstName ">
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
</template>
```

**operatorStep.js**

```
import { ElectronicRegistrationForm } from 'model/electronicRegistrationForm';
import { inject, NewInstance } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { RegistrationWizard } from 'registration/registrationWizard';
import { WizardStep } from 'registrationSteps/wizardStep';
import { ValidationController } from 'aurelia-validation';
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(ElectronicRegistrationForm, RegistrationWizard, NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class OperatorStep extends WizardStep {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) operator;

  constructor(electronicRegistrationForm, regWiz, validationController) {
    super(electronicRegistrationForm, regWiz, validationController);
    this.operator = electronicRegistrationForm.operator;
    this.operator.firstName='First name from operator step';
    this.representative = electronicRegistrationForm.legalRepresentative;
  }
}
```

**operatorStep.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="common/operator-detail"></require>
  <form validation-renderer="bootstrap-form">
    <operator-detail operatorvalue.bind="operator"></operator-detail>
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a bindable property on a template is for when you have a View without a ViewModel.

The `bindable="operatorvalue"` in your **operator-detail.html** doesn't work because you also have a ViewModel defined for this element. If you want to keep it this way then simply remove the `bindable="operatorvalue"` from the template and instead declare it in your ViewModel like so:

```
import {inject, NewInstance, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ValidationRules, ValidationController} from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class OperatorDetail {
    @bindable operatorvalue;

    constructor(validationController) {
        this.validationController = validationController;
        this.firstName = '';
    }

    attached() {
        ValidationRules
            .ensure('firstName').displayName('Ime').required()
            .on(this);
    }          
}
```

**operator-detail.html** would then become:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName" t='first_name'></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" value.bind="operatorvalue.firstName ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Alternatively, you could make the bindable property declaration in the template work by simply deleting **operator-detail.js** and putting the validation stuff elsewhere. Then, rather than injecting OperatorDetail into the registration form you could new up the operator object like so:

```
import { LegalRepresentative } from 'common/legalRepresentative';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(LegalRepresentative)
export class ElectronicRegistrationForm {
    constructor(legalRepresentative) {
        this.operator = {};
        this.legalRepresentative = legalRepresentative;
    }
}
```

Both ways will work.

Working without ViewModels means putting the validation logic in **electronicRegistrationForm.js** for instance, which also means less code to write.

Working with ViewModels gives you more encapsulation, which is generally preferable if your view-specific logic is more complex than what you've shown here.

**EDIT**

In case you're using Google Chrome, I highly recommend using the [aurelia context](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aurelia-context/cghchmoikhedpkkkdnljcfhikedoemma) extension. You could then inspect the html and see that **operator** was defined in **operator-step**, but **operatorvalue** was undefined in **operator-detail**. This would tell you that the **operatorvalue** bindable declaration must be wrong, rather than something else.